# Tab can not navigate and Tabs hide behind the main screen

Tags: android, tabs, textview, overlay

In my android app main screen has couple of panel. In the first panel consist of two tab, which display the predefine database information as a list view. Problem is when the main screen show the database information it overlay the two tab, basically tab function is not reachable anymore. Is there any way to give line space or clear distinction before textview ? Please see the image file. Thanks for any suggestion or recommendation.

[image]

XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingTop="0px" >

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>

</TabHost>
```

Java Code

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.event_panel);

TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

TabSpec spec1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 1");
spec1.setIndicator("Text-1");
Intent in1 = new Intent(this, Tab1.class);
spec1.setContent(in1);



TabSpec spec2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 2");
spec2.setIndicator("Text-2");
Intent in2 = new Intent(this, Tab2.class);
spec2.setContent(in2);


tabHost.addTab(spec1);
tabHost.addTab(spec2);

tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(160, 35));
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(160, 35));
```

Comment: Please add some code and or xml

Answer (score 0):

It seems you set the layout programmaticly try to change the height at this line:

```
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(290, 35));
```

35 seems to small, pick a higher number that should solve it I guess

Comment: I was changing this value to see the difference. My Tab button are in backend now and list view is top of the screen :(

Comment: Can you be more specific, or add an image to show the result?

Comment: Please kindly look at first screen, the list view hide the two tabs top of the screen, so basically I can not even press any tab button. Please note. all the list information I'm retrieving from the DB. In my emulator I can navigate with key so tab page certainly exist there.

Comment: So changing the values did not work and you end up with the same result?

Comment: Changing the value resize the Tab icon. Tab button are not clickable, since list view information hide the Tab view.